# Ocultar e mostrar div depois de um determinado tempo

Tags: jquery, css, html5

Estou criando a tela de um sistema que vai mostrar uns gráficos e vai ser exibidos em um TV. Existe duas class uma .tela-01 e outra chamada .tela-02 que esta com display:none. Gostaria que ficasse alterando entre essas duas telas a cada 10 segundos, os exemplos que achei na internet só funciona uma única vez, assim que carrega a tela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria basicamente um `if` alternando as duas `div`s com `.hide` e `.show()` usando `setInterval`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   setInterval(function(){
      
      if($(".tela-01").is(":visible")){
         $(".tela-01").hide();
         $(".tela-02").show();
      }else{
         $(".tela-02").hide();
         $(".tela-01").show();
      }
      
   }, 10000);
});
```

```css
.tela-02{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tela-01">Tela 1</div>
<div class="tela-02">Tela 2</div>
```

Uma forma sem `if`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   setInterval(function(){

      var tela = "[class^='tela-']:";

      $(tela+"visible").hide("fast", function(){
         $(tela+"hidden")
         .not(this)
         .show();
      });
      
   }, 10000);
});
```

```css
.tela-02{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tela-01">Tela 1</div>
<div class="tela-02">Tela 2</div>
```

Comment: Obrigago cara, era exatamente isso que eu precisava

Comment: Disponha cara! Adicionei uma outra forma sem if. Abs!